# ReactJS setState from asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey ReactJs Community,

I am fairly new to ReactJs and have gotten my first components set up. Now I'm at a point where I would like to update all state items on a specific event. I am looping each state item via `map()` and am calling a asynchronous method to determine a value to be included in the state.
This method is returning GET data via the callback function.

```
updateItems: function() {
    var items = this.state.items;
    items.map(function(item, i) {
        checkConfirmation(item.hash, function(confirmations) {
            console.log("Item " + i + " has " + confirmations + " confirmations!");
            items[i].hash = item.hash + " (" + confirmations + ")";
            items[i].completed = true;
        });
    });
}
```

**How can I update my state from the asynchronous callback?**

I tried passing in `this` as the second parameter in `map()` and I tried calling `setState` after the map() function, but that cannot work since it will be called before any data is returned in the callback.

Thank you for taking time to help me with this issue!

Comment: Is `checkConfirmation` returning something?  Why are you using `map` and not `forEach`?

Comment: @ctrlplusb `checkConfirmation` is async, that means it can't return something because we dnt know when the data will be available to us. I used `map` because most ReactJS tutorials and the official siteuse it, too. What is the advantage over both?

Comment: It's just that map is used to transform an array from one type to another in general.  I don't think it's appropriate for your use case.

Comment: is your async callback, just so I know I am reading your code correctly or you are not excluding code, the callback IN "checkConfirmation" function? So, you map - make an async call on EACH mapped item.. right?

Comment: @james emanon yes, I am checking the confirmed state from a Webserver for each item in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a promise for each pending request. Await them all using `Promise.all`. And set state when all requests are done.

```
updateItems: function() {
    const items = this.state.items;

    const pending = items.map(item => new Promise(resolve => {
        checkConfirmation(item.hash, resolve)
    }))

    Promise.all(pending)
      .then(confirmations => confirmations.map((confirmation, i) => {
        const item = items[i]

        // copy items mutating state is bad
        return Object.assign({}, item, {
          completed: true,
          hash: `${item.hash}(${confirmation})`
        })
      }))
      .then(items => this.setState({ items })
}
```

*UPD* Callbacks hackery

```
updateItems: function() {
    const items = this.state.items;
    let confirmations = []
    let loaded = 0

    const addConfirmation = i => confirmation => {
      confirmations[i] = confirmation
      loaded++;

      // if all were loaded
      if(loaded === items.length) allConfirmationsLoaded()
    }

    const allConfirmationsLoaded = () => {
        const newItems = confirmations.map((confirmation, i) => {
            const item = items[i]

            // copy items mutating state is bad
            return Object.assign({}, item, {
              completed: true,
              hash: `${item.hash}(${confirmation})`
            })
        })

        this.setState({items: newItems})
    }

    // for each item lauch checkConfirmation
    items.forEach((item, i) => {
      checkConfirmation(item.hash, addConfirmation(i))
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will try it at home and mark this as the corrent answer if it works.

Comment: This answer does require a Promise library, though. I am using React Web with the Babel library. Is there a solitude that does not require a additional dependency?

Comment: Actually native Promises are supported in major browsers. But sure you can use callbacks. If you hate future maintainers :)

Comment: The code from your answer works like I hoped. I did not know Promises were natively supported. This solution is very clean. Thank you!